# Keep groups where at least one element satisfies condition in pyspark

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark

I've been trying to reproduce in pyspark something that is fairly easy to do in Pandas, but I've been struggling for a while now.
Say I have the following dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,2,1,1,2], 'b':[12,5,1,19,2,7]})
print(df)
   a   b
0  1  12
1  2   5
2  2   1
3  1  19
4  1   2
5  2   7
```

And the list

```
l = [5,1]
```

What I'm trying to do, is to group by `a`, and if any of the elements in `b` are in the list, then return `True` for all values in the group. Then we could use the result to index the dataframe. The Pandas equivalent of this, would be:

```
df[df.b.isin(l).groupby(df.a).transform('any')]

   a  b
1  2  5
2  2  1
5  2  7
```

Reproducible dataframe in pyspark:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,2,1,1,2], 'b':[12,5,1,19,2,7]})
sparkdf = spark.createDataFrame(df)
```

I was currently going in the direction of grouping by `a` and applying a pandasUDF, though there's surely a better way to do this using spark only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've figured out a simple enough solution. The first step is to filter out rows where the values in `b` are in the list using `isin` and `filter`, and then keeping the unique grouping keys (`a`) in a list.

Then by merging back with the dataframe on `a` we keep groups contained in the list:

```
unique_a = (sparkdf.filter(f.col('b').isin(l))
                   .select('a').distinct())
sparkdf.join(unique_a, 'a').show()

+---+---+
|  a|  b|
+---+---+
|  2|  5|
|  2|  1|
|  2|  7|
+---+---+
```